# How to get data in DB2 SQL, limit the number of rows returned and also SUM those rows for one column?

Tags: sql, db2, sum

I have a simple query that returns some records:

```
select reference as ref, amount as amt
from my.table
where foo_ref like 'B%'
and foo_amount != 0.000
fetch first 12 rows only
```

What I would also like to do is to SUM the amt column for these 12 returned rows.  I am a newbie to SQL so I am not sure how this is done.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY`, the fetch-first clause gives you undefined results.  Your best bet will be wrapping this in a subquery or CTE before the sum.  What do you want to happen to `ref`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version and release of DB2?  There's some powerful OLAP functionality in current versions..

```
with tbl as (
   select reference as ref, amount as amt
   from my.table
   where foo_ref like 'B%'
     and foo_amount != 0.000
   order by ref
   fetch first 12 rows only )
select tbl.*, sum(amt) as tot_amt 
from tbl  
group by rollup ((ref,amt))
```

This will return 13 rows, with the 13th containing NULL for ref and amt while having the total for the 12 rows in tot_amt.

Comment: This did the trick.  Thanks a ton, Charles and thanks to those who also replied.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select reference as ref, SUM(amount) as amt
 from my.table
 where foo_ref like 'B%'
 and foo_amount != 0.000
 group by reference
 fetch first 12 rows only
```

The SUM() adds the values in amount. I added a group by for the reference. The result will be a table that is a group of references with a sum of the amount.

Any time you use a SUM(), COUNT(), MAX(), MIN() - et cetera you also have to add a group by to fields that are not using these functions.

Comment: No.  Adding the `GROUP BY` means you get 12 rows of different `ref` values with their sums, not a sum over 12 rows.  This result would be wildly different.

Comment: It really depends on what the values in reference are. If you want a simple SUM of only the amount then you would either have to drop the reference or you would need to pick a MIN/MAX or FIRST/LAST. If you did that then chances are the referance is not going to be representative of the SUM of the amount. Because no data sample was given there is no way to tell.